# Is there an #IF DEBUG for Asp.net markup?

Tags: asp.net, debugging

Can I do something like this in the markup of an asp.net page, based off the "Define DEBUG constant" setting?

```
#IF (DEBUG) THEN
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">You're in debug mode</asp:TextBox>
#END IF
```

Comment: The wrong answer was set as the correct one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The close as I can get is:

```
<asp:Literal id="isDebug" runat="server" />
<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load()
    {
#if DEBUG
        isDebug.Text = "You're in debug mode";
#endif
    }
</script>
```

This would give you problems if you wanted to have anything else in your Page_Load() event; the literal code above only works if the page/control has no code behind.

If I needed to do this, I would encapuslate the above code into a user control and include that control in the pages of interest.

My test user control looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  %>
<asp:Literal id="isDebug" runat="server" />
<script runat="server">    
    void Page_Load()    
    {
#if DEBUG        
        isDebug.Text = "You're in debug mode";
#endif    
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 62):

```
<form runat="server">
 <% #if DEBUG %>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">You're in debug mode</asp:TextBox>
 <% #else %>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server">Mmm... No, I think you're not in debug mode</asp:TextBox>
 <% #endif %>
</form>
```

Note that you cannot assign the same ID for those text boxes.

Also note that DEBUG is true when it is set so in web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true">
```

Comment: is there a way to set debug automatically true when debugging and vice versa ?

Comment: @Guy `DEBUG` indicates whether or not you're using a Debug Build (As opposed to a Release build / others). I think what you want is `Debugger.IsAttached` or `HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled` - Will be true if launched from within VS, false otherwise (unless you manually attach a debugger of course)

Comment: From my experience this works only if you have declared in the header of your ASPX or ACX file `<%@    CompilerOptions="/d:DEBUG" %>`. 

But then it does not automatically switch when you turn from debug to release. 

**Note** you can define multiple variables this way if you separate them with semicolon, e.g. `<%@    CompilerOptions="/d:myVar1; myVar2" %>`. Each of these can be checked by using a `<% #if myVar %>`statement.

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to step through javascript or prefer to minify javascript when not debugging, I prefer this approach:

```
<% if (Debugger.IsAttached) { %>

  <script src="jquery.js"></script>

<% } else { %>

  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<% } %>
```

I can easily step through code when I am debugging, otherwise I want the scripts to be minified. Be sure to include the following import:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Diagnostics" %>
```

Moreover, it is nice to use the Web Essentials visual studio extension to bundle/minify your javascript files so that there is only one request made to the server for your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Literal and then using #if DEBUG in your code-behind to inject html for your textbox into the literal? Also there are direct code blocks in ASP.NET but I don't know if they deal with #if statements; those seem to be reserved for the C# compiler.

Answer (score -1):

It would be easy enough to roll your own.  You might miss some of the cooler non-compiling features of Compilation Constants but you'd definitely have the ability to add markup based on a global parameter of some sort.