# Site.css to Debug mode, site-min.css to release mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, conditional-compilation

In my view like that in debug mode to view Site.css use her, and when compiled in release mode the view using CSS-min.css site.

**Something like this:**

```
# if (Debug)
             / / CSS
# elif (Release)
             / / CSS Min-
# endif
```

But in my view **.cshtml**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Context.IsDebuggingEnabled`. This boolean property is controlled by the **debug attribute** from the **compilation section** in web.config.

Here's a sample for your view.cshtml :

```
if (Context.IsDebuggingEnabled)
{
    // use something.css
}
else
{
    // use something.min.css
}
```

Comment: Does not work!
I compile in release mode and `Context.IsDebuggingEnabled` property = true

PS: in my Web.Release.config

<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" debug="false" />

Comment: Its because the compilation inside Visual Studio never use the transform feature. He always use web.config wherever you are in Debug or Release mode. The transformation occur when you publish your website. For a quick test, just change the debug attribute inside web.config.

Comment: It worked!
If you change manually works.
Well, it helps me, but it's strange, I would like to work whenever you select how to build in toolbar

Comment: you are right that it is strange that visual studio doesnt transform the .config files on build. It would be great to have this feature in the next Visual Studio version since that its just a normal behaviour of the build process to use the right config file depending of the build mode!

Comment: It's not strange. If you want Web.config file is transformed on build so where is it after build successfully? You don't want original Web.config file is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

[asp.net mvc - Razor view engine, how to enter preprocessor(#if debug) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696175/razor-view-engine-how-to-enter-preprocessorif-debug/4697570#4697570)

How about this?