# Several custom configuration in #if directive

Tags: c#, visual-studio, custom-configuration

I need the following logic

```
#if (DEV || QA || RELEASE)
//add when dev or qa or release configuration
#endif
```

Is it possible in c#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Quoting the [`#if` documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx):

> You can use the operators `&&` (and), `||` (or), and `!` (not) to evaluate whether multiple symbols have been defined. You can also group symbols and operators with parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define DEBUG 
#define MYTEST
using System;
public class MyClass 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
#if (DEBUG && !MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG is defined");
#elif (!DEBUG && MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("MYTEST is defined");
#elif (DEBUG && MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG and MYTEST are defined");
#else
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG and MYTEST are not defined");
#endif
    }
}
```

Here simple code how to do it. You can read full documentation on [C# Preprocessor Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx)

Comment: Is it possible to do this in cshtml file?

Comment: @PavelIvanov you can check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696175/razor-view-engine-how-to-enter-preprocessorif-debug. There are various ways to do it, you can check best method suited for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [These are called "preprocessor directives" or compiler directives](http://www.davidarno.org/c-howtos/define-and-other-c-preprocessor-directives/).