# AngularJS: Remove development section when running in production

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

I'm developing an *AngularJS* application inside Visual Studio 2013. I've added a custom HTML template with some debugging form fields to manipulate my scope when developing the site:

```
<div data-ng-include="'App/Development/development.html'"></div>
```

This is fixed in the bottom left corner and make it easier for me to quickly do some actions when testing the site.

But this should be removed when I deploy my website (Release configuration).

Does anyone have a good solution for doing this? Currently my App config and AngularJS is not integrated, so there is no way to tell my Angular application that it is running in production mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696175/razor-view-engine-how-to-enter-preprocessorif-debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to just check the hostname, if `localhost` I'm showing my development bar.

```
app.controller('development', function ($scope) {
    $scope.debug = document.location.hostname == "localhost";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you are using mvc with razor

Create a cs file

```
public class ConfigManager
{
    public static bool IsDebugMode()
    {
        #if DEBUG
           return true;
        #else
           return false;
        #endif
    }
}
```

get the value

```
<script>
  app.value('myValue', @ConfigManager.IsDebugMode());
 <script>
```

On your angular controller

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, myValue)  {
  //use myValue
      $scope.isTestMode = myValue;
 });
```

html

```
<div data-ng-show="isTestMode" data-ng-include="'App/Development/development.html'"></div>
```

Comment: But how can I make that property change depending on build configuration in Visual Studio (Debug, Release etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Put an ng-clock on it so the div will not show before angular loads and an ng-if so you will not load ("include") needed sources for a regular user. have the service/controller check the host(property of the window object). if it's local, show the panel using ng-if. you can also have it check the query string. so you can debug on remote by affixing ?debug=true to the Url for example.