# How to remove console.log lines on release build?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, console.log

I've got some web projetcs in Visual Studio 2013. Each web project has a debug and a release build profile.
How could I do to perform some cleaning of the JavaScript console.log("here is a log message") when the project is built (or after) ?
For information, I already use bundles with minification (from System.Web.Optimization).

Comment: if the console.log statements are on the rasor view this answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696175/razor-view-engine-how-to-enter-preprocessorif-debug

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap `console.log` in your application, so that you have fine grained control over logging at runtime.

That said, this is a dirty temporary hack:

```
debug && console.log('foo');
```

Where debug can be defined at runtime to start logging to the console.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just do a "Find & Replace" on "console.log" to "//console.log".

If you use a minifier when deploying, it will strip the comments out to clean up the code.

Answer (score 0):

VS CODE

Open the search option in the sidebar menu
Type in console.log.*$