# How I can check debug mode in MVC cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, razor

How I can check debug mode in MVC cshtml page? this code not working in cshtml page.

```
@{
bool isRelease = false;
#if DEBUG
 isRelease = false;
#else
 isRelease = true;
#endif
}
@{
if(isRelease)
{ < p > result1 < /p > }
else
{ < p > result2 < /p >}
}
```

application display "result 2" but it must display "result 1"

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696175/razor-view-engine-how-to-enter-preprocessorif-debug

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check these:

```
HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
```

Reference:
[IsDebuggingEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.isdebuggingenabled.aspx)

Comment: Tyle  this worked  HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled