# Is it possible to put #if debug in the html page?

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to add #if debug property to cshtml pages codes as it is done in the controller class in .Net Framework? Is there a valid html code or feature so I can do this? can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an #IF DEBUG for Asp.net markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378982/is-there-an-if-debug-for-asp-net-markup)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378982/is-there-an-if-debug-for-asp-net-markup  In this question, a solution has been written for aspx codes, but this solution is not available on the cshtml page in .Net Mvc.